# Infer Method-Return Type which is generic type of another type

Tags: c#, generics, methods, type-inference

I've got a generic base class with one implementation:

```
public abstract class Setting<T> : ISetting
{
    public T DefaultValue { get; }
}

public class SubscribeToNewsletterSetting : Setting<bool>
{
   ...
}
```

Now I've got a settings class, using this settings:

```
public class UserSettings
{
    public TSetting GetSetting<TSetting>(int ownerId)
        where TSetting : ISetting
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I can use the `UserSettings` class like this:

```
var setting = settings.GetSetting<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22);
var settingsValue = setting.DefaultValue;
```

Now I was wondering - Is it possible to do this in one step, without specifing the type: e.g:

```
var settingsValue = settings.GetSettingDefaultValue<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22);
```

(I do not want to call it like this)

```
var settingsValue = settings.GetSettingDefaultValue<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting, bool>(22);
```

Cheers,
Manuel

Comment: User does not know the "core type", but knows `SubscribeToNewsletterSetting` one?

Comment: Could you add a (pseudo-code) example of the desired usage? I'm not quite sure what you mean with "core-type". I'm assuming the `bool` in `class SubscribeToNewsletterSetting: Settings<bool>`?

Comment: @PeterE - yes. Thanks, I've edited the question

Comment: Maybe it's sully question, but how this will compile `where TType : ISetting`? `TType` isn't defined, only `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Type inference of generic parameters is an all or nothing proposition. Either all parameters can be inferred and you have to (explicitly) specify none, or you have to specify them all explicitly.

You only have the choice between the following to variants:

```
public class UserSettings
{

    // Variant A
    public TSetting GetSetting<TSetting>(int ownerId)
        where TSetting : ISetting
    {
        return default;
    }

    // Variant B
    public TValue GetSettingValue<TSetting, TValue>(int ownerId)
        where TSetting : Setting<TValue>
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this. Where `x,y,z` should all be implicitly typed as `bool`.

```
class Demo
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var us = new UserSettings();

        // Variant A
        var x = us.GetSetting<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22).DefaultValue;

        // Variant B 
        var y = us.GetSettingValue<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting, bool>(22);

        // desired, but impossible
        var z = us.GetSettingValue<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22);
    }
}
```

---

My recommendation would be to add a `public T Value {get;}` property to `Settings<T>` and add the database access code (or at least the strong typing part of it) to 'SubscribeToNewsletterSetting' (where the TValue type is known).

Comment: "and add the database access code (or at least the strong typing part of it) to 'SubscribeToNewsletterSetting'" - don't think that it's a good idea, database access code should be on another level, let say the creator of `UserSettings` instance should correctly specify values, otherwise you bound smth like DTO to the type of concrete storage, which is for sure bad by different aspects

Comment: I'm wondering - what is the reason for this?
When it comes to syntax, why not allow something like this?


```TParam Get<TType>(int id) where TType : ISetting<TParam>```

Comment: Well, if one reasons systematically it become somewhat obvious why it probably is what it is. Still annoying thou. 1) A method signature must be fully definable (i.e. be unambiguous). 2) Generic type placeholders represent allowed points of variance. 3) But to be able to achieve unambiguity there must be some kind of list of all used placeholders; these basically are the generic type parameters. This explains why they must be all specified when defining a method. (Also: Otherwise things like reflection would not work).

Comment: 4) The question now becomes, why must we specify them all (or none) when using them. My guess is: simplicity. When all types can be infered, all is well. But if for example only one of two can be infered by the compiler, then the other one would have to be specified by the programmer. Only, how should the compiler know if you just provided the first or the second parameter? Perhaps that could be deduced in some if not most cases, but I'm fairly sure there will be edge cases where it is not possible. Then you would need some kind of syntax construct like named type parameters.

Comment: As you can see this spirals in complexity quickly.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correctly understood question you want to consider instance of `SubscribeToNewsletterSetting` also as a `boolean` value, if so... then you can do next:

```
    public abstract class Setting<T>
    {
        public T DefaultValue { get; }

        public static implicit operator T(Setting<T> value)
        {
            return value.DefaultValue;
        }
    }

    public class SubscribeToNewsletterSetting : Setting<bool>
    {
    }


    public static async Task Main()
    {
        ...
        // Will work fine.
        bool isEnabled = settings.GetSetting<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22);
    }
```

Comment: @ManuelR.Wenk, so... you want to assign `DefaultValue` of `SubscribeToNewsletterSetting`  to `settingsValue` variable using next one line `var settingsValue = settings.GetSettingDefaultValue<SubscribeToNewsletterSetting>(22)`? If so, then i have edited my answer...

Comment: Yes, I would like to receive a bool in this case, and when I ask for SomeNameSetting : ISetting<string> I would like to receive a string. The type shall be inferred.

Comment: @ManuelR.Wenk, then presented code will work in this way

Comment: @AlexanderTolstikov but only if you explicitly type `isEnabled` as `bool`. I'm guessing that`s also not desired.

Comment: @PeterE, then this will be impossible in a strongly typed programming language, except the situation as in my previous answer, where override of an implicit operator is specified in the target class itself, but this will produce too much of duplications per every child of Settings<T> if `DefaultValue` will be used constantly :)

Comment: @Alexander Tolstikiv But my question was about type inference at the level of GetSetting. It's about how the GetSetting method is able to infer the T in Setting<T>. 
In the implementation of GetSetting, I would like to decide to return the defaultValue or something stored in a database.

Comment: @ManuelR.Wenk, then it will be impossible without explicit specifying of T from Settings<T>, or inside GetSettings<TSettings> you should use something not strongly typed, like reflections or `dynamic`, but after that, your code will be a little bit messy. 
For example 
`GetSettings<TSettings>(object whoknows) { Type tsettingsType = typeof(TSettings); Type tType = tsettingsType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
// now you know T type of TSettings and should implement logic related to this info   }`

Comment: @PeterE, "@AlexanderTolstikov but only if you explicitly type isEnabled as bool. I'm guessing that`s also not desired."
 - then interesting how the variable will be used in future if the user of code don't know the type of this variable:)

Comment: @AlexanderTolstikov I think the whole point of this question is to avoid having to type `bool`. As soon as one specifies `SubscribeToNewsletterSetting` it should theoretically be possible for the compiler to infer the type of `TValue`. It just does not do it. If a method has two generic type parameters you either have to specify both or none. Even if the second one is already implicated by the first. I have ran into this myself before and it is rather annoying at times.